# How to get key and value of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I have object as `var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]`  . I want to get key and value this sample

```
PRODUCT_ID is P01
M01 is 1
M02 is 2
M03 is null
```

I try with as follow

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " is " + obj[key]);
  }
}
```

It't not working , it's show wrong with format.

```
0 is [
1 is {
2 is "
3 is P
4 is R
5 is O
6 is D
...etc
```

I using javascript to this. If maybe can convert to json and show this .

Comment: Seems  `obj ` is string, Can you share the output of `typeof obj `?

Comment: Oh, Do you have idea for this ?

Comment: It's array of objects with one object in it. delete "[ ]" and try again.

Comment: @BrianCrist I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observation :**

`for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. Hence, As per the code in OP **:**

```js
var obj = [{
 "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
 "M01": 1,
 "M02": 2,
 "M03": null
}];

for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(key); // 0
}
```

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = [{
 "PRODUCT_ID": "P01",
 "M01": 1,
 "M02": 2,
 "M03": null
}];

for (var i of obj) {
  for (var j in Object.keys(i)) {
    console.log(Object.keys(i)[j] + " is " + i[Object.keys(i)[j]]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the object you receive is a string not an actual object or array. This is why with your code, it gives the output.

To convert to an actual JS object use `JSON.parse()` and it will return an array as expected.

For instance,

```
const myArray = JSON.parse(obj);
myArray.forEach(x => Object.entries(x).map(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key} is ${value}\n`)))
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are querying `obj`, while the actual obj is `obj[0]`. `obj` is an array with 1 element. try this

```js
var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}];

for (var key in obj[0]) {
  if (obj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " is " + obj[0][key]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's right. If you could change your `obj` definition to: `obj = {"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}`, it'll be more readable

Comment: It is quite clear, that OP has not an object, please read the question.

Comment: @Teemu, it is quite clear that is exactly what I meant by *the actual obj is obj[0]*

Comment: Read the question, take a careful look over the provided output, what you see?

Comment: @BrianCrist, please show the error or some relevant feedback, since it is working in the snippet, I cannot tell what the problem is, do you happen to have more than 1 element in your array `obj` in your real scenarios?

Comment: @Teemu: I see the OP wants `PRODUCT_ID is P01` `M01 is 1` `M02 is 2` `M03 is null` which is exactly what the snippet is outputing

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't solve the problem OP's facing.

Comment: @Teemu literally: *I want to get key and value this sample:*

Comment: Literally read the question ... "_It't not working , it's show wrong with format._" Then what you see? The characters of the so called object one by one ... OP has not an object, they have a string, and that is their first problem to solve, without solving that any answer will be totally useless.

Comment: @Scaramouche  , i get this in console.log ```0 is [```

Comment: @BrianCrist, so just to be sure, in the snippet I provided it works, but in your dev env is throwing `0 is [`? are you sure you are using `var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]` as test input. earilier I asked you if `obj` (which you should really change the name to `arr`, since we've established it's an array, not an object) has only 1 element or it could have more

Comment: @Scaramouche , as same as Teemu said,

Answer (score 1):

use Object.keys() method to access the keys in your object and then simply concatenate the key with its value.

this is not the most elegant solution, but it will help you understand.

```js
var obj = '[{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]' //string
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(Object.keys(obj[0])) //so that you can see what this does

obj.forEach(object => {
   Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
       $("#values").append($("<p>"+key +" is "+ object[key]+"</p>"));  
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="values">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry , I get with ```["0"]```

Comment: I understand that he has an array of object/s and the answer attends to that

Comment: maybe he edited the question to make it an array? even so, i will attend to that too.

Comment: @Teemu see snippet for string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like:

```js
const jsonString = '[{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]'

// parse your json string first
const arr = JSON.parse( jsonString );

// Get the object from the array
const obj = arr[0] || {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key + ' is '+value);
}
```

Comment: @BrianCrist Please try to use `JSON.parse` first to get actual array from the JSON string like show in the demo above.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that you are treating an array like an object. Change your code for:

```
for(x=0;x <obj.length;x++){
    // Here you have each object of your array.

     var json = obj[x];
     var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys (json);

    //other code.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const input = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]

// Output.
input.map(x => Object.entries(x).map(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key} is ${value}\n`)))
```

Comment: It is quite clear, that OP has not an object, please read the question.

Comment: "I have object" @Teemu

Comment: That's what they think, look at the output.

Comment: @Teemu i think we should change to json or array . Do you think so ?

Comment: @BrianCrist At first you've to do `JSON.parse` to parse your string to an object, then follow some of these answers.

Comment: @Teemu  Exactly, and i must what do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost correct. But as you have data array not object you need to loop trough the object to achieve desire output.

***Guessing OP has:***

```js
var obj = '[{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]';
    for (var key in obj) {
         console.log(key + " is " + obj[key]);
    }
```

```js
//var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]
var obj = '[{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]';
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
for (var key in obj) {
  for (var k in obj[key]){
     console.log(k + " is " + obj[key][k]);
    }
}
```

**Alternative:**

```js
//var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]
var obj = '[{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]';
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, v]) => console.log(k, "is", v)))
```

Comment: Your code is almost correct, except it doesn't solve the problem OP is facing. Don't you guys read the questions anymore? Almost all the answers on this post are somewhat useless for OP, including this ...

Comment: @Teemu what OP wants? How to get key and value of object in javascript?

Comment: Yep, but the gotcha is, that they don't have an object ... Like I said, don't you guys read the questions anymore?

Comment: what do you mean they don't have an object? Op clearly said *I have object as var obj = [{"PRODUCT_ID":"P01","M01":1,"M02":2, "M03": null}]*

Comment: Please read the entire question! The output of the provided `for ..in` loop would totally be different from what OP says they're getting, if they had an object ...

Comment: Please explain. I read the question and failed to understand your point.

Comment: Then we should ask OP to provide proper question. I can't assume what OP have. I just copy the object from question. I guess it might be a string then we can use JSON.parse()

Comment: @Teemu Please review my updated post. I think you mean this. Thanks for the information.